# deploy c# windows application with localdb and install it on client machine

Tags: c#

i developed small c# windows application with localdb usin vs2015 and i deployed it with db worked very well on my computer but when i install it on other computer th database didnt work , so where is the problem

my connection string 
is

```
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\alfahrasdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

when i start the program on any computer it says that db is already exist or cant open

thank you

Comment: The data source is pointing to LocalDB. Does the database exist on the local computer or some other machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is wrong ,for deployment and access db from another system you must install sql server ,create a server on a system and 
change your data source to the url of the system where sql server installed
**(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB** to **Data Source=servername\DBName**

Comment: I already installed sql server on the other computer and install sql server 2014 express localdb , but where i found the server name ??

Comment: open sql server managment studio > view object explorer>there is a box on top for connect object explorer click on that>there you find server name if you configured

Comment: Why i must install sql server management studio on other computer ?? I add local db from visual studio because i dont want to use sql management studio to creat database and when i deploy the project i add . Mdf files with deployment files .  All are include. I was think that just i must install sql 2014 localdb on other computer . Is that right or not ??

Comment: [sql server run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006152/how-to-run-application-with-sql-database-on-a-machine-that-dosent-have-sql-serv?rq=1) click link and hopefully this will solve your issue